# Adding value of zero for missing rows after a group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe and let's say my data keeps track of people who enter my shop.
My data looks like:

| Name | month | day | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | October | 31 | 5 |
| John | October | 31 | 6 |
| Jane | October | 31 | 6 |
| Albert | October | 31 | 8 |
| Albert | October | 31 | 9 |
| John | October | 31 | 10 |
| Jane | October | 31 | 11 |
| Albert | October | 31 | 12 |
| John | October | 31 | 12 |
| Emily | October | 31 | 12 |
| Albert | October | 31 | 20 |
| Emily | October | 31 | 21 |
| John | October | 31 | 23 |
| Jane | October | 31 | 23 |
| Albert | November | 1 | 5 |
| John | November | 1 | 6 |
| Jane | November | 1 | 6 |
| Albert | November | 1 | 8 |
| Albert | November | 1 | 9 |
| John | November | 1 | 10 |
| Jane | November | 1 | 11 |
| Albert | November | 1 | 12 |
| John | November | 1 | 12 |
| Emily | November | 1 | 12 |
| Rose | November | 1 | 15 |
| Elizabeth | November | 1 | 16 |
| Karen | November | 1 | 16 |
| Albert | November | 1 | 20 |
| Emily | November | 1 | 21 |
| John | November | 1 | 23 |
| Jane | November | 1 | 23 |

I group by month, day, hour to get the count of my customers, and I get:

| count | month | day | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | October | 31 | 5 |
| 2 | October | 31 | 6 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 8 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 9 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 10 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 11 |
| 3 | October | 31 | 12 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 20 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 21 |
| 2 | October | 31 | 23 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | November | 1 | 12 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 21 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 23 |

However, I want to add into the data also the "0", and get something like:

| count | month | day | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | October | 31 | 0 |
| 0 | October | 31 | 1 |
| 0 | October | 31 | 2 |
| 0 | October | 31 | 3 |
| 0 | October | 31 | 4 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 5 |
| 2 | October | 31 | 6 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 8 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 9 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 10 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 11 |
| 3 | October | 31 | 12 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 20 |
| 1 | October | 31 | 21 |
| 2 | October | 31 | 23 |
| 0 | November | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | November | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | November | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | November | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | November | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | November | 1 | 12 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | November | 1 | 21 |
| 2 | November | 1 | 23 |

Is there a way to programmatically do that?

Comment: Provide your input data as code.

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```
import calendar  # note only used to revert month to literal

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create a new dataFrame counting people for each day
# note the renaming
hourly_data = df.groupby(['month', 'day', 'hour'], as_index=False).count().rename(columns= {'Name': 'count'})

# Create a datetime column
# use pd.to_datetime on a string for the date and hour
# note insertions 1/ of a year, 2/ of minutes 
hourly_data['DH'] = pd.to_datetime(hourly_data['day'].map(str) + " " + hourly_data['month'].map(str) + " " + '2021' + " " + hourly_data['hour'].map(str) + ":00")

# Keep only the needed columns
hourly_data = hourly_data[['DH', 'count']]

# Create the missing rows by setting an index with a hourly frequency
# note sorting to avoid some errors
hourly_data = hourly_data.set_index('DH').sort_index().asfreq('h')

# Fill the missing values for created rows with 0  
hourly_data['count'].fillna(value = 0,  inplace = True)

# Now we can revert count to int
hourly_data['count'] = hourly_data['count'].astype(int)

# Create columns from the index
hourly_data['year'], hourly_data['month'], hourly_data['day'],  hourly_data['hour'] = hourly_data.index.year, hourly_data.index.month, hourly_data.index.day, hourly_data.index.hour

# and convert month to litteral
hourly_data['month'] = hourly_data['month'].apply(lambda i:calendar.month_name[i])

# Reorder columns
hourly_data = hourly_data[['year','month', 'day', 'hour', 'count']]
```

Assuming the following data:

```
import io

s = """
Name   month    day hour
Albert October  31  5
John   October  31  6
Jane   October  31  6
Albert October  31  8
Jane   October  31  23
Albert November 1   5
John   November 1   6
Jane   November 1   6
Albert November 1   8
Albert November 1   9
John   November 1   10
Jane   November 1   23
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
```

hourly_data :

```
                     year     month  day  hour  count
DH                                                   
2021-10-31 05:00:00  2021   October   31     5      1
2021-10-31 06:00:00  2021   October   31     6      2
2021-10-31 07:00:00  2021   October   31     7      0
2021-10-31 08:00:00  2021   October   31     8      1
2021-10-31 09:00:00  2021   October   31     9      0
2021-10-31 10:00:00  2021   October   31    10      0
2021-10-31 11:00:00  2021   October   31    11      0
2021-10-31 12:00:00  2021   October   31    12      0
2021-10-31 13:00:00  2021   October   31    13      0
2021-10-31 14:00:00  2021   October   31    14      0
2021-10-31 15:00:00  2021   October   31    15      0
2021-10-31 16:00:00  2021   October   31    16      0
2021-10-31 17:00:00  2021   October   31    17      0
2021-10-31 18:00:00  2021   October   31    18      0
2021-10-31 19:00:00  2021   October   31    19      0
2021-10-31 20:00:00  2021   October   31    20      0
2021-10-31 21:00:00  2021   October   31    21      0
2021-10-31 22:00:00  2021   October   31    22      0
2021-10-31 23:00:00  2021   October   31    23      1
2021-11-01 00:00:00  2021  November    1     0      0
2021-11-01 01:00:00  2021  November    1     1      0
2021-11-01 02:00:00  2021  November    1     2      0
2021-11-01 03:00:00  2021  November    1     3      0
2021-11-01 04:00:00  2021  November    1     4      0
2021-11-01 05:00:00  2021  November    1     5      1
2021-11-01 06:00:00  2021  November    1     6      2
2021-11-01 07:00:00  2021  November    1     7      0
2021-11-01 08:00:00  2021  November    1     8      1
2021-11-01 09:00:00  2021  November    1     9      1
2021-11-01 10:00:00  2021  November    1    10      1
2021-11-01 11:00:00  2021  November    1    11      0
2021-11-01 12:00:00  2021  November    1    12      0
2021-11-01 13:00:00  2021  November    1    13      0
2021-11-01 14:00:00  2021  November    1    14      0
2021-11-01 15:00:00  2021  November    1    15      0
2021-11-01 16:00:00  2021  November    1    16      0
2021-11-01 17:00:00  2021  November    1    17      0
2021-11-01 18:00:00  2021  November    1    18      0
2021-11-01 19:00:00  2021  November    1    19      0
2021-11-01 20:00:00  2021  November    1    20      0
2021-11-01 21:00:00  2021  November    1    21      0
2021-11-01 22:00:00  2021  November    1    22      0
2021-11-01 23:00:00  2021  November    1    23      1
```

and hourly_data is of type

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 43 entries, 2021-10-31 05:00:00 to 2021-11-01 23:00:00
Freq: H
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   year    43 non-null     int64 
 1   month   43 non-null     object
 2   day     43 non-null     int64 
 3   hour    43 non-null     int64 
 4   count   43 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 2.0+ KB
```

Above the type of the index `DatetimeIndex` and its frequency `Freq: H`
Yhe index is kept as it can be useful for some downstream processing.